# __dirname no me funciona

Tags: nodejs, express, multer

estoy intentando subir unas imagenes a mi proyecto nodejs por medio de multer, mi configuracion multer es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y esto es mi directorio de carpetas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que al ejecutar se me crea la carpeta public/img afuera de mi src, y lo que busco es que se cree dentro de mi carpeta src. Que puedo hacer ?

Comment: Generalmente no es buena idea guardar tus archivos en la  carpeta `src`, pero solo agregale a `__dirname+'/src'` y creo que debería funcionar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__dirname` hace referencia a la ruta absoluta del directorio que contiene el archivo que se está ejecutando actualmente, por esa razón crea la carpeta en esa ubicación. Si lo que deseas es crear la carpeta dentro de otro directorio, deberías agregar la ruta completa a partir del directorio del archivo que se esta ejecutando.
Viendo tu estructura de carpetas, estaría quedando algo parecido a esto:

```js
app.use(multer({
    storage,
    destination: path.join(__dirname, '../public/img/')
}).single('image'));
```

Dicho esto, es un estándar dejar la carpeta **public** en el directorio raíz. Fuera de cualquier otra carpeta.
Espero te sea útil